# web page not displaying special characters

Tags: android

I have an ".HTML" file which is stored in the "res\raw" folder.
I used the following code to display the contents of my file:

```
static String TAG="WebPageShowActivity";
    WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webpagedisplay);
        String summary = readRawTextFile(this,R.raw.spotlighterhelp);
                //getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.spotlighterhelp).toString();
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL (null,summary, "text/html","ASCII" ,null);
    }
     public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId)
     {
          InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

          InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
          BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
          String line;
          StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

          try {
            while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
              }
          } catch (IOException e) {
              return null;
          }
          Log.e(TAG, "file content: "+text.toString());
          return text.toString();
     }
```

now, my problem is: Whatever be the type of encoding, it is not displaying special characters like " or ' What do I do so that these characters are shown too?

Following is the output I am getting
[image]

Comment: Problem solved. I had converted the .doc file to .html, hence I had converted the "" into some special character "". Replaced them now it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may works, Try to use `UTF-8` instead of `ASCII` for your webView.

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL (null,summary, "text/html","UTF-8" ,null);
```